# R Shiny - bookmarking dynamically created UI

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks, shinyjs

I came across slight problem (bug maybe?) with Shiny's bookmarking - I create dynamically UI - new text and numeric inputs. These inputs are created by clicking on an ActionButton. When saving the bookmark URL - the values of numeric and text inputs are both in this URL. So far so good. However after loading the saved URL I only see the first dynamically created UI. I have to click the actionbutton to add the next numeric and text inputs. The values are saved in the URL and once these inputs are added, they are filled with the correct saved values. But it's slightly inconvinient if you have 20 of these buttons and you have to click 19 times to get them all onto your screen.
Here is a short reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request){
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    bookmarkButton(),
    sidebarLayout(
      actionButton('addElement', 'Add Element', icon("plus"), class="btn-success text-white"),
    mainPanel(
        id ="content"
      )
    )
  ))
}


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  enableBookmarking("url")
  countvar <<- 0
  observeEvent(input$addElement, {
    countvar <<- countvar + 1
    element <- paste0("var", countvar)
    insertUI(
      selector = "#content",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tagList(
        wellPanel(
          style = "display:-webkit-inline-box;width:100%",
          id = element,
          column(3,
                 textInput(element, "Element name")
          ),
          column(3,
                 numericInput(paste0(element, "Value"), "Element Value", NULL)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })

})
```

I found similar question on SO, unfortunately unanswered - [Shiny app bookmarking: dynamic UI input lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679431/shiny-app-bookmarking-dynamic-ui-input-lost)

Comment: You need to use the `onRestore()` function. Take a look at this article: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html

Comment: Hi Barbara, thanks for the link. I think I see where the problem is - even that in the URL the addElement has value of more than 1, it is only triggered once. However I am not sure how should I incorporate the `onRestore()` function into my code. What exactly should I be calling - triggering the "observeElement" part of code? Or simply parsing in the pure HTML? Thanks, I'm a bit lost at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a minimal example adapted from your app. There's no magical way to get dynamic content on the page after bookmarking (unless you use renderUI in a straightforward way -- i.e. without any non-input state). So, for your case, you just have to repeat the work you do in the app again inside the `onRestore()` callback. The best way of doing this is to refactor your code, so that there's a function that can be called to add the item both in the normal app and inside the `onRestore()` callback.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    bookmarkButton(),
    sidebarLayout(
      actionButton("add", "Add Element"),
      mainPanel(id = "content")
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  addItem <- function(id, textId, numberId, textVal = "", numberVal = NULL) {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#content",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tagList(
        wellPanel(style = "display:-webkit-inline-box;width:100%",
          id = id,
          column(3, textInput(textId, "Element name", textVal)),
          column(3, numericInput(numberId, "Element value", numberVal))
        )
      )
    )
  }

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    id <- paste0("var", input$add)
    textId <- paste0(id, "text")
    numberId <- paste0(id, "number")
    addItem(id, textId, numberId)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

  onRestore(function(state) {
    for (i in seq_len(input$add))  {
      id <- paste0("var", i)
      textId <- paste0(id, "text")
      numberId <- paste0(id, "number")
      addItem(id, textId, numberId, input[[textId]], input[[numberId]])
    }
  })
}

enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I was afraid that that will be the case - I have quite a lot of this dynamically generated content, so overall it will be a bit messy. Thanks a lot for your time, appreciate the input!

Comment: Also I realised that I can use a function inside of the observeEvent handlerExpr. Therefore I have created a function which I call ib both observeEvent and during the onRestore phase. So far it's working just fine.

Comment: @ledogbert Wondering if you could post the code you used to create a function to be handled by observeEvent and onRestore. I am trying to do something similar but the restore is failing without any kind of useful error message...

Answer (score 2):

This is an new answer extending Barbara's one. It seems that we need to reference the state variable for the `onRestore` function to work properly with the user's inputs. So I changed her code to include a `state$input$var` that seems to work. Hope it helps.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {
    fluidPage(
        bookmarkButton(),
        sidebarLayout(
            actionButton("add", "Add Element"),
            mainPanel(id = "content")
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    addItem <- function(id, textId, numberId, textVal = "", numberVal = NULL) {
        insertUI(
            selector = "#content",
            where = "beforeEnd",
            ui = tagList(
                wellPanel(style = "display:-webkit-inline-box;width:100%",
                          id = id,
                          column(3, textInput(textId, "Element name", textVal)),
                          column(3, numericInput(numberId, "Element value", numberVal))
                )
            )
        )
    }

    observeEvent(input$add, {
        id <- paste0("var", input$add)
        textId <- paste0(id, "text")
        numberId <- paste0(id, "number")
        addItem(id, textId, numberId)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

    onRestore(function(state) {
        for (i in seq_len(input$add))  {
            id <- paste0("var", i)
            textId <- paste0(id, "text")
            numberId <- paste0(id, "number")
            addItem(id, textId, numberId, state$input[[textId]], state$input[[numberId]])
        }
    })

}

enableBookmarking("server")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```